# Linq query is not returning the expected result. 3 tables join

Tags: c#, linq, join

I try to count records what are belong to an applicants using Linq query but its not returning with the expatced result. Multiplication occurs.
The actual applicants has:

- 2 application
- 6 course

How join tables to get right values (2 and 6)?

Thank you!

```
var q = from application in this.SzakokRepository.GetAll()
                    join course in this.ErettsegiRepository.GetAll() on application.JelentkezoId equals course.JelentkezoId
                    join applicants in this.JelentkezokRepository.GetAll() on application.JelentkezoId equals applicants.Id
                    where applicants.Id == jelentkezoID
                    select new
                    {
                        Jelentkezo = applicants, //1 pieces
                        Szak = application, //2 pieces
                        Erettsegi = course, //6 pieces
                    };
            var result = from g in q
                         group g by g.Jelentkezo.Id into grp
                         select new HelperErettsegiSzak
                         {
                             JId = grp.Key,
                             CountedApplications = grp.Count(), //12 pieces
                             CountedCourses = grp.Select(x => x.Erettsegi.Id).Count(), //12 pieces
                         };
            return result.ToList();
```

Comment: Please show the sample data, what you _expected_ it to return and what was _actually_ returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty much expected actually. You have flat mapped your `applicants`, `application` and  `course` basically multiplying 1*2*6 = 12 in your join clause, then grouped by key which is the same for all in the join result and have a group of 12 items. Try adding `Distinct` clauses in your counts (assuming `Szak` has some unique `Id` field):

```
var result = from g in q
        group g by g.Jelentkezo.Id into grp
        select new HelperErettsegiSzak
        {
             JId = grp.Key,
             CountedApplications = grp.Select(x=> x.Szak.Id).Distinct().Count(), 
             CountedCourses = grp.Select(x => x.Erettsegi.Id).Distinct().Count(), 
        };
```